# LEGO EV3: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python-3.x, lego-mindstorms-ev3

First of all I'm new Python programmer.
I get an understanding error in the very simple code below:

```
from pybricks.hubs import EV3Brick

def getbatV(lego):
    v=lego.battery.voltage()
    return(v)

def getbatI(lego):
    i=lego.battery.current()
    return(i)

ev3 = EV3Brick()
intensite = getbatI(ev3)
voltage = getbatV(ev3)
print("   Paramètres au repos: ", voltage, '--', intensite)
```

I confirm that getbatV & getbatI refer to correct Lego instructions.
But the code give this result:

```
Paramètres au repos:  None -- None
```

Translated:

```
Parameters at rest: None -- None
```

I presume that ev3 was not correctly initiated? So what can I do to do it?

Have a nice day,

Henri

Comment: Of course it is.
But I agree this is important before to ask! :-)